# NTP works but clock is not the same

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ntp

I'm trying to sync multiple machines (9 machines that are cloned from one machine so they have exactly same config) on a LAN using NTP.
All machines are running FreeBSD 10.2 on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 as host OS & without guest additions.
I'm using both the Ubuntu host and default servers of ntp as time server:

```
logfile /var/log/ntpd
driftfile /var/db/ntp.drift
logconfig=allsync + allclock

server pool.ntp.org iburst
server 192.168.1.110 iburst
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

It seems NTP is working:

```
root@vccc:~ # ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*192.168.1.110   173.44.32.10     3 u    8   64    1    0.168   36.817   0.280
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 176.9.253.76 (n 129.70.132.33    3 u    1   64    1  231.664   99.656  17.441
```

But when I check time on two machines (using synced panes on tmux) at the same time they are not the same :

```
# for i in {1..5};do date && sleep 1; done │# for i in {1..5};do date && sleep 1; done
Mon Dec 21 00:43:52 IRST 2015              │Mon Dec 21 00:43:32 IRST 2015
Mon Dec 21 00:43:53 IRST 2015              │Mon Dec 21 00:43:33 IRST 2015
Mon Dec 21 00:43:54 IRST 2015              │Mon Dec 21 00:43:34 IRST 2015
Mon Dec 21 00:43:55 IRST 2015              │Mon Dec 21 00:43:35 IRST 2015
Mon Dec 21 00:43:56 IRST 2015              │Mon Dec 21 00:43:36 IRST 2015
```

What is with NTP?
How can I make all machines have exactly same time?

**Edit**
I Used `TZ=UTC date` as @chexum suggested but got the same result:

> **Machine 1:**   Sun Dec 20 22:53:00 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 2:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:59 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 3:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:47 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 4:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:31 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 5:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:59 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 6:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:39 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 7:**   Sun Dec 20 22:53:00 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 8:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:45 UTC 2015
>
> **Machine 9:**   Sun Dec 20 22:52:39 UTC 2015

And here is the output of `ntpq -pn|grep '*'`:

```
Machine #1:  
*194.225.150.25  193.67.79.202    2 u   13   64    1   15.677   57.252   9.383

Machine #2:  
*194.225.150.25  193.67.79.202    2 u   16   64    1   17.431   77.865  26.331

Machine #3:  
*192.168.1.110   91.189.94.4      3 u   16   64    1    0.618  106.251  49.607

Machine #4:  
*194.225.50.25   129.70.132.33    3 u   16   64    1   16.556  258.324 111.098

Machine #5:  
*194.225.50.25   129.70.132.33    3 u   19   64    1   16.290   95.826  34.486

Machine #6:  
*192.168.1.110   91.189.94.4      3 u   18   64    1    1.111  132.498  79.517

Machine #7:  
*194.225.150.25  193.67.79.202    2 u    2   64    1   15.815   33.073   1.654

Machine #8:  
*194.225.50.25   129.70.132.33    3 u   19   64    1   15.812  135.808  58.548

Machine #9:  
*192.168.1.110   91.189.94.4      3 u    1   64    1    0.148   48.311   0.015
```

Comment: If you stop ntpd on one of those machines and run "ntpdate 192.168.1.110" (to pick one of your NTP servers), what offset does it report? (then restart ntpd)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the actual timezone configuration file?  ~20 seconds difference suggests there is a mismatch between the time zones, and one is configured with leap seconds, the other without leap seconds:

```
> TZ=right/Europe/London date; TZ=Europe/London date
Sun Dec 20 22:34:45 GMT 2015
Sun Dec 20 22:35:10 GMT 2015
```

Perhaps it's easier to check if `TZ=UTC date` prints the same time on all machines to rule out differences in the time zones.

This should account for 26 seconds exactly though (1 additional seconds difference can be explained if checked right at the second boundary).  Are you sure both of the above clients have synched perfectly by now?

Some GPS sticks are notorious about forgetting the leap seconds differences as well, but if all your clients are using the same NTP server, this cannot have an effect - only if you use a (bad) local GPS device as the NTP time source.

Comment: All of my machines are cloned from one base machine so the configuration of them are exactly the same! anyway I checked the `TZ=UTC date`  (please check my edit) and got the same result (actually there are 9 machines and 4 of them have different times; I'm using same NTP config for all of them and I don't have any GPS (the 192.168.1.110 itself is synced to pool.ntp.org)

Comment: Ok, what I can't see now, if ntp did actually complete the synchronization yet - can you check whether `ntpq -pn|grep '*'` indeed shows up on all the clients?

Comment: I added the result from all machines to question

Comment: All have selected a time source, but all different - interesting.  Though all have just recently started, with a single synchronization attempt (`reach`).  If ntpdate has not been run before, ntpd can delay the switching to a time source for a prolonged time.  If VM time management (unreliable scheduling) is the cause, you'd see log messages and/or ntpd would stop reporting `*` after a few hours (perhaps as long as a day.)

Comment: I don't think VM does anything as guest additions are not installed and `CoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution` is set to 0 for all machines

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like NTP did not run ntpdate at startup to correct the ~15 second discrepancies. NTP has selected preferred servers but is having to gradually slew the time into sync. Try stopping ntpd; run ntpdate against any reachable ntp server, then restart ntp.

Comment: Making sure you don't have any time-sensitive apps running while you do it, of course (databases, for example)

Comment: I do this every time at boot but as soon as I start ntpd again I have same result

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you're saying that `ntpdate <server>` synchronizes the time, but when you then start ntpd, the server times are unsync'd again? Sounds to me like something else is interfering with the clocks.